# WatchKit: sync a timer between watch and iPhone app?

Tags: watchkit

The problem I'm facing is that I started a count down timer(which is implemented with `NSTimer`) on iPhone app, and I want the user to see the timer on his Apple Watch, which has installed the counterpart watch app.

Now the only way I can communicate between watch and iPhone is by writing the start date and end date in `NSUserDefault` so that watch app can read it and adjust the timer according to its wall time.

But what if there is a time difference between the watch and iPhone, or since they are connected with bluetooth, the time will always be accurate in both ways?

Answer (score 2):

I am doing something similar in my WatchKit app. I have a count down timer in my GlanceController that is using WKInterfaceTimer.

There is no time difference between the watch and the iPhone. I tested this on a real watch. They are exactly in sync.